# How to associate a second degree equation to a bridge arch.

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

[image]

The bridge connects two hills 100 feet apart. The arch on the bridge is in a parabolic form. The highest point on the bridge is 10 feet above the road at the middle of the bridge. Find the equation of the parabola.

My working :

I assumed the middle point of the bridge as (0,0) One end of the bridge is (-50,0) and other end is (50,0) the highest point is (0,10)
Let us assume that the equation of the parabola is $$y =-ax^2 +bx + c $$

As this equation satisfy the above three points therefore,

0 = -2500a -50b+c ....(i) [ by putting x = -50, y = 0 ]

0 = -2500a +50b +c ....(ii) [ by putting x = 50, y = 0 ]

10 = c ....(iii)  [ by putting x = 0, y = 10 ]

Is this the correct approach , as i am not getting the answer given in the options.

Please guide on this .. thanks

Comment: What are the options?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: The center of the bridge is hanging below the two ends.  If you are using the center of the bridge for your origin, the ends of the bridge are not $(-50,0)$ and $(50,0$, the $y$ values are incorrect.

Comment: No, these are not hanging below the two ends, it is a flat road, the bridge is supported by a road in the middle with a height of 10 units from centre.

Comment: Answer is $-250y =x^2$ ,can you please explain how ??

Comment: If you take the highest point as the origin and the road below x-axis, equation of parabola will be $-250y =  x^2$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach, leading to the equations (i)–(iii), is correct. It gives $b=0$ (since the bridge is symmetric), $c=10$, and $a={1\over250}$. The equation of the actual parabola then is
$$y=-{x^2\over250}+10\ .$$

Comment: But the answer is $x^2=-250y$

Comment: @sultan: The equation $x^2=-250y$ means that the arch passes through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

parabola equation
$ x^2 = -4ay$

it is given that height 10 feet is at the middle of the bridge. So a point on parabola is (50,-10).
By putting point in above parabola equation,
$(50)^2 = -4a*(-10)$

so, $a = 2500/40$

$ a = 250/4$

hence, required equation is : $x^2 = -250y$

have a nice day..........

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).